# Get Parent ID of this DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to find the parent div id (i.e. "Bakerloo") from this layout when the button is clicked within ".buttonleft0" in jquery / javascript.

```
<div id='Bakerloo' class='box'>bakerloo<p></p><span class='buttons'>
<span class='buttonleft0'><button onClick='up()'><span class='icon icon10'></span>
</button>
</span><span class='buttonleft'></span><span class='buttonright'></span></span>
<div class='comingup'></div>
<div class='more'></div></div>
```

I have tried:

```
$(this).parent('id');
```

But this just returns 'undefined'.

Comment: Typo in your code, `<div>class='comingup'>`

Comment: pass in this in your inline onClick `onClick='up(this)'`.. though it would probably be better to bind with jQuery since you are already using jQuery

Answer (score 5):

```
$(this).closest('div').attr('id')
```

I think this is what you want

Comment: $(this) will take the object that calls the function so if you are not sure that that points to the button you should use a locator for the button eg: $('span .buttonleft').closest('div').attr('id')

Answer (score 5):

Straight up Javascript always works for me.

```
<div id='Bakerloo' class='box'>
    bakerloo<p></p>
    <span class='buttons'>
        <span class='buttonleft0'>
        <button onClick='alert(this.parentNode.parentNode.id)'>
             <span class='icon icon10'></span>
        </button>
        </span>
        <span class='buttonleft'></span>
        <span class='buttonright'></span>
    </span>
    <div class='comingup'></div>
    <div class='more'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The `parent()` function returns the jQuery object, so you need to use the `attr()` for any of it's attributes like so:

```
$(this).closest().attr('id');
```

**Edit:** On further inspection it appears the button isn't the direct child of the `div`, and so use of the `closest()` function would be required.

Comment: Even when you correct the typo that @j08691 pointed out in his comment?

Answer (score 2):

Your code itself have few errors so here is the correct one:

**HTML**

```
<div id='Bakerloo' class='box'>bakerloo<p></p><span class='buttons'>
<span class='buttonleft0'><button><span class='icon icon10'>Click here</span>
</button>
</span><span class='buttonleft'></span><span class='buttonright'></span></span>
<div class='comingup'></div>
<div class='more'></div></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("button").on('click',function(){
       alert($(this).closest('div').attr('id'));
    });
});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cpeeyush/ydk4e/

Comment: @ldmosel good.. if it works for you then please accept the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(this).parent().attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$(this).closest('div[id]')

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($(this).parent().id);
```

If you want to be sure to select correct class, try:

```
alert($(this).parent('.div').id);
```

If you have a deeper hierarchy you can use:

```
alert($(this).parents('.div:eq(n)').id);
```

where n is which parent you want to get